# Is there a parameter we can add to a KT1 contract so that it expires after a certain amount of blocks?

Tags: smart-contracts

I'm asking because I would like certain KT1 addresses return the funds back to the owner after a certain amount of blocks

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built-in function for this. However, it can be accomplished with a smart contract, that when called by the owner after a certain deadline returns its balance. Currently, the deadline must be specified as a timestamp, but future versions of Michelson may include a `LEVEL` instruction (see this [merge request](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/tezos/merge_requests/94)). It returns the block level of the current transactions, and so could be used to implement the behavior your describing.

However, there is currently now way of "expiring" or "suiciding" a contract in Michelson. Deployed contracts stay on the block chain forever. However, you can implement the contract so that after a certain deadline (specified using a timestamp or the `LEVEL` instruction described above), all incoming calls are rejected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Say you reach that timestamp and there are still coins on the KT1 address, will those coins become untouchable in this scenerio?

Comment: If you write the contract so that it always fails after the given timestamp, yes the tokens will be locked forever.