# How to define Tezos Contract start and end date?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client

Developing Smart Contract for Tezos, How i can define Tezos Contract start and end date ? it should only work between given date.

Comment: See the answer to the following question: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/is-there-a-parameter-we-can-add-to-a-kt1-contract-so-that-it-expires-after-a-cer/1835